# PHP's shuffle() says that it needs an array, when I give it an array

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm in the middle of throwing an easy project together in order to familiarize myself with php; I am coming from a C# background. One of the things I'm running into is the concept of type awareness, as there is none... not really. For example:

```
<?php

include_once 'Player.php';
include_once 'DeckOfCards.php';

class Dealer extends Player {
    public $deck;

    public function __construct($name){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->money = 10000;
    }

    public function setNewDeck(){
        $this->deck = new DeckOfCards();
        return true;
    }

    public function dealCard(){
        return array_pop($deck);
    }

    public function shuffleDeck(){
        shuffle($this->deck);
        return true;
    }
} ?>
```

The problem is that when the `shuffleDeck()` function is called, I get the warning:

```
shuffle() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in MyFirstPhpProject\Object\Dealer.php on line 23
```

What am I missing about this approach here?

Comment: The error is quite clear: the function wants an array, and you've given it an object (an instance of `DeckOfCards`). If this object is a container for all cards, then you'll probably want to do your shuffling inside that object, e.g. `$this->deck->shuffle();` - with the `shuffle` method for you to write in the other class.

Comment: Your code is effectively - `$this->deck = new DeckOfCards; shuffle($this->deck);` You're giving it an object - where is the array coming from?

Comment: Proposition: Shuffle works (with arrays); `$x = array(1,2,3); shuffle($x)`. Conclusion: An array *wasn't* passed.

Comment: OH CRAP... mixed myself up. The deck of cards object has a deck property that is the actual array... thanks. I guess i just needed another set of eyes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
        $this->deck = new DeckOfCards();
```

will return an object, not an array.

What you need is something that retrns an array. You might need to do thus:

```
$myDeck = new DeckOfCards();
shuffle($myDeck->getDeck()); // where DeckOfCards::getDeck() returns an `array()`
```

Comment: A better solution would be to do `$myDeck->shuffle()`, and have the `DeckOfCards` class handle shuffling internally, possibly by calling `shuffle()` on a private array.

Comment: I totally derp'd the fact that the Deck of cards object holds the array as a property. It's $this->deck->deck that I want in this instance. I should refactor this...

Comment: Don't shuffle `$this->deck->deck` from inside `Dealer` - the attribute on `DeckOfCards` should not be public, and `Dealer` should not be able to see the internals of that class. Use a method instead (heh, yes to what @jcsanyi said).